# how to delete records from array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, store

I'm trying to delete some records of an array to display it after but when I delete records, nothing is deleted.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {        
Ext.create('BVCore.Grid', {
    id:'gridServiceCatalogAll',
    renderTo: 'gridServiceCatalogAll',
    stateId: 'gridServiceCatalogAll',       
    store: Ext.create('BVCore.LocalStore', {
        fields: ['id','category', 'name', 'equipment', 'sizeMin', 'sizeMax', 'description', 'annualCharge'],
        groupers:[grouper],
        proxy: {
            url:  '<spring:url value="/controller/search/json/serviceCatAll.json" />'               
        },
        listeners:{
             load: function(store, records) {
                 Ext.each(records, function(record, index){
                     Ext.each(records, function(rec, ind){
                         if((record.get('category') == rec.get('category')) && (record.get('annualCharge') == rec.get('annualCharge')) && (record.get('id') != rec.get('id'))){
                             store.remove(rec);
                         }
                     }, this);
                 }, this);
             }
        }
    }),
    features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
    columns: [
              {text: '<spring:message code="serviceModel.category" />', dataIndex: 'category'},
              {text: '<spring:message code="serviceModel.description" />', dataIndex: 'description'},
              {text: '<spring:message code="serviceModel.annualCharge" arguments="${year}" />', dataIndex: 'annualCharge'}                       
          ]
});
```

});

Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: at what point are you showing it? can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to delete an attribute of an object,
here is how you do it.

```
var obj = {'foo':'bar'}
delete obj.foo
console.log(obj); //Object {}
```

Comment: I made this but no result, however it enter under the if

Answer (score 0):

For an array use splice: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)